# Splitting string before and after certain parameters in Go

Tags: string, go

My string splitting skills are really poor using Go. I don't know why but I just can't wrap my head around this one and I've tried different ways to do what I need but I always get the wrong output.

I have this string:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k2RNDSh6K7jH3fezjjfgVrHqVstBF569al4F28hqAM/edit#gid=0
```

I need to get a key from this URL that is found after '/d/' up until the next '/'.

So the key in this case would be:

```
1k2RNDSh6K7jH3fezjjfgVrHqVstBF569al4F28hqAM
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`strings.Index`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Index) can help you with this:

```
s := "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k2RNDSh6K7jH3fezjjfgVrHqVstBF569al4F28hqAM/edit#gid=0"
i := strings.Index(s, "/d/") + len("/d/")
j := strings.Index(s[i:], "/") + i
fmt.Println(s[i:j]) // Prints "1k2RNDSh6K7jH3fezjjfgVrHqVstBF569al4F28hqAM"
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/Mqnnc_tNFk.

Comment: Note that this could panic if the second call to index returns `-1` because `"/"` was not found. Then `i > j` in `s[i:j]` which causes panic.

Answer (score 3):

I have never used "go" but it looks like you could utilize

```
func Split(s, set string) []string
```

Example:

```
fmt.Printf("%q\n", strings.Split("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1234567890/edit#gid...", "/"))
```

would return the array

```
["https:" "" "docs.google.com" "spreadsheets" "d" "1234567890" "edit#gid..."]
```

Answer (score 1):

Go 1.18 will come with `func Cut(s, sep string) (before, after string, found bool)`, from [issue 46336](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/46336) and [CL 351710](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/351710/)

```golang
s := "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k2RNDSh6K7jH3fezjjfgVrHqVstBF569al4F28hqAM/edit#gid=0"
_,after,found := strings.Cut(s, "/d/")
if found {
    // after is 1k2RNDSh6K7jH3fezjjfgVrHqVstBF569al4F28hqAM/edit#gid=0"
    before, _, _ := strings.Cut(after, "/")
    // before is 1k2RNDSh6K7jH3fezjjfgVrHqVstBF569al4F28hqAM
    fmt.Println(before)
}
```

No more `Index()` and `SplitN()`.
A lot of places in stand lib will benefit from `strings.Cut()`: [CL 351711](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/351711/).

Answer (score -1):

There are many alternatives to do this, here is the one which I used regular expression.

```
s := "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k2RNDSh6K7jH3fezjjfgVrHqVstBF569al4F28hqAM/edit#gid=0"
re := regexp.MustCompile("/d/(.*)?/").FindAllStringSubmatch(s, -1)
fmt.Println("found the pattern :", re[0][1])
```

https://play.golang.org/p/l6B4AE-4to

Comment: [Benchmarks in Go](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Benchmarks) are easy so it's not opinion if it will be "more faster". Using a regexp for such a simple task is [~17× slower](https://play.golang.org/p/OM8a51129d) and does three vs zero allocations (and that's with precompiling the regexp only once in a global).